# Android authorization with Google for my own server

Tags: java, android, google-signin, google-account, java-server

So I'll start from the beginning. I want to create an Android application and a server (written in java). The server will be written in Java. What I want to do is to be able to log in to my server from the Android application, using the Google account. After the device is logged in, there will be some information sharing with HTTP Requests. I want to use REST.

How should I proceed for achieving my goal? I guess I should use the Google API and Google App Engine. What should I do to implement the log in and the part in the server. It's first time for me writing a server and an application with log in, so any advises will be appreciated. The application is for educational purposes. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what about https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenIDConnect?

Comment: I would imagine that you're question hasn't received enough attention because you're not willing to do any work on your own side. It's been 2 days since you asked this question and there is no new information as to what you've looked into or tried to figure out on your own. You can hire someone to do the research and development for you, but when asking questions here it's best to try on your own and approach when you encounter problems. This is not a problem, this is a lack of research.

Comment: I don't want my job to be done by someone else. I just want some steps to follow or something. I need advises. Also why should I hire somebody when this project is not for commercial usage? I'm sorry if I didn't expressed properly. I need the approach, not the code. 
I will answer to my question if I figure put what to do by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really suggest you give [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/) a try, specially combining it with [Cloud endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/) which are designed to connect your server to clients like an Android App. Using endpoints you'll get cloud infrastructure + REST services + native libraries ( for Android, JS and iOS) and everything related to authentication is already sorted out (via OAuth).

App Engine can also be developed using Java and it's already integrated with popular IDEs like Eclipse (through the Google Plugin) and Android Studio (as backend modules) so you prbably have everything you need to star working on your App Engine server.

Comment: You know how  you can log in with facebook, g+, etc. to use some services, provided from some webpages for example. I want to the same in my app. What I want to do maybe can be done without any registration from the users but for future development of the project maybe I'll want the users to be able to connect to each other. I don't want to make them create a new registration, so you are telling me that GAE, REST services and Cloud endpoints are a good approach?

Comment: **Yes** you can either implement your own auth schema or use 3rd party OAuth providers like G+ or FB, github, twitter, etc. eg: https://github.com/loudnate/appengine-endpoints-auth-example . So you users dont need to create credentials on your site. You will probably have to store OAuth keys and whatnot, but thats totally transparent to the user.

Comment: Should I use something for my server to create the REST api, something like Jersey, or Google provides the tools for this? Sorry for asking, you don't have to answer this, I can search it by my own, I just think it will be good if you add it in your answer. I'm thinking of accepting it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thats Google cloud endpoints i mentioned earlier. You get rest API generation + free ui for api + native libs for android, ios and js. Its an awesome product but only works off App Engine servers

Comment: Yes, I saw already that it works only on Google App Engine. Since it is not for commercial usage, it wont be a problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Play services (you don't need App Engine).

Here is the complete process with code samples:  [Authorizing with Google for REST APIs](https://developer.android.com/google/auth/http-auth.html)

Another option you can look at: [Google+ Sign-in for Android](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in)

On the server side, once you have the auth token, you access the Google REST API with the username and token, and Google will tell you if the access is authorized.

I understand what you're trying to do.  Your user already has a username and credentials on Google, why not just get the username and let Google do all the authentication?

However, you might want to re-think this approach.

The problem is that you will ask your user to sign in to Google and Google will ask the user (through logic in the Android API code) if your application can have access to their information in Google.  Your users may balk at granting that kind of access to your application, and that will hamper your efforts to get people to use your app.

Now, if your app actually *uses* the Google REST APIs, then this would make more sense, because the auth token your app requests will provide access to a Google API.

But if all you're doing is authenticating, your users might be hesitant to authorize your app for some Google operation they don't think you need.

To get a feel for the OAuth 2.0 message flow, you can use this: [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)